# How would I get a string representation of a web page's source from URL in C?

Tags: c, http

How would I get a string representation of a web page's source from URL in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to download it, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is a pretty nifty library for fetching files from many different kinds of servers, including HTTP.